Accessing Twilio Voicemail Recordings in Polycom VVX250 Phones
We're using Twilio for calls and Polycom VVX250 phones. We have an SIP domain and credentials configured on Twilio and the Polycom phones. Our system checks a database to route calls based on linked IP phones and sends Twiml responses. Voicemail recording works using the Twiml Record verb, but the recordings are stored in Twilio.
Question: How can we access these Twilio voicemail recordings directly within the Polycom phone's voicemail section?
Note: We're not using a PBX, everything is cloud-based.

To manually access voicemail recordings from Twilio via Polycom VVX250 phones, would technically require integration between the Twilio voicemail recordings and your Polycom phone system. You are effectively connecting the dots between the functionality provided by your Polycom phone and the voicemail being hosted by Twilio. In general, you would:

Store Voicemail Recordings in an Accessible Location
Transfer Voicemail Recordings to Your Server (Twilio Webhook)

Express Js Twilio webhook example
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.post('/voicemail', express.urlencoded({ extended: true }), async (req, res) => {
  const recordingUrl = req.body.RecordingUrl;
  const recordingSid = req.body.RecordingSid;
  const callSid = req.body.CallSid;

  if (recordingUrl && recordingSid) {
    // Fetch the recording from Twilio
    const response = await axios({
      url: `${recordingUrl}.wav`,
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'stream'
    });

    // Save the recording to your server
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'recordings', `${recordingSid}.wav`);
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

    response.data.pipe(writer);

    writer.on('finish', () => {
      console.log(`Recording saved: ${filePath}`);
    });

    writer.on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(`Error saving recording: ${err.message}`);
    });
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});


Thanks, But where to add this endpoint URL in Polycom phone?

The webhook URL will be on Twilio Console then configure the phone’s voicemail settings to point to the server where the recordings are stored.
Here is the flow
Set Up a Voicemail Server (configure it to store recordings) - Ensure it is accessible via SIP or IMAP - Configure the Polycom VVX250 Phone (Settings -> Lines) - Configure Voicemail Parameters ( Voicemail Number: The number or URI used to access the voicemail server, User ID: The username or extension number for accessing voicemail, Password: The password for the voicemail account.)

Same answer given by chatGPT and I tried it all, Its not working. Is this working for you?
